MySQL can values statement columns be named?
I have searched on the forums and failed to find how can one name columns for a values statement subquery.
Here is my query in MySQL:
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    ('PPA', 'blah', 30)
    , ('PPB', 'blah blah', 60)
) AS X

Here is what I can do in T-SQL:
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c
FROM (VALUES
    ('PPA', 'blah', 30)
    , ('PPB', 'blah blah', 60)
) AS x(a, b, c)

Very simple, yet can't find out.
Note: As I know this query can be simplified to no subquery, my question remains as this will be merged into another query for an insert and a left join of mine.

Why has this been downvoted? I think the issue is well explained. (It only lacks the error message that MySQL raises on the T-SQL query.)

@ThorstenKettner The question shows that it has been viewed 25 times, and presumably the most intolerant person out of those 25 decided it needed to be downvoted. This is the problem with SO's downvote system (or maybe internet-based voting systems in general): it gives a disproportionate weight to outliers.

You are almost there just need to add ROW.
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ROW('PPA', 'blah', 30), 
    ROW('PPB', 'blah blah', 60)
) AS X (a, b, c);

Result:

More about ROW you can read here and here.

Weird. In the docs you've linked to, they say that (1,2) and ROW(1,2) are equivalent. Still, ('PPA', 'blah', 30) and ROW('PPA', 'blah', 30) obviously aren't.

I.e. this doesn't solve OP's problem naming columns.

@ThorstenKettner, Row constructor is same as in both ways. But when using with VALUES statement documentation ask to add ROW() as row constructor. Added that doc as well in the answer. And yes it looks weird :D

@jarlh It is naming the column in that order. Xanadu is asking for the same answer, because you can see his T-SQL.

From what I could find further on looking at MariaDB,
you could use common table expressions as such:
WITH t(a, b, c) AS (
    VALUES
    ROW('PPA', 'blah', 60)
    , ROW('PPB', 'blah blah', 60)
)
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
FROM t

from source

You could use a union as well
SELECT 'PPA' AS a, 'blah' AS b, 30 AS c
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PPB' AS a, 'blah blah' AS b, 30 AS c

